# I need to pass a combobox to a class method using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, object, controls

I have a custom class that handles the gathering of my serial COM ports using WMI which works as expected.  Now, I would like to pass the WMI query values to my combobox which I already did when not using a class. However, I am trying to clean up my code and place sections into a class.  I am now trying to pass my combobox to my class method located in a separate .cs file by passing the Form object that the combobox resides on.  I tried: `public void getSerialPorts(Form f)`, but when I press f. I do not see my combobox in the dropdown list that Visual Studio creates.  I do not think my combo object has been passed correctly.  Can someone present a simple example on how to pass a form control object to a class method to manipulate them later?

code segments:
Form1.cs

```
        private void computerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bsetup.getSerialPorts(this);
        }
```

setup.cs

```
    public void getSerialPorts(Form f)
    {

        try
        {
            string wmiresult;


            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%mbed% %Serial% %Port% %(COM%'");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                wmiresult = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

                // Here we call Regex.Match.
                Match match = Regex.Match(wmiresult, @"\bCOM\d+\b");

                // Here we check the Match instance.
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    //combo.Add(queryObj["Caption"].ToString(), match.Value);
                    //comboBox1.Items.Add();
                    MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + er.Message);
        }
    }
```

Working Example

```
private void computerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ports = bsetup.getSerialPorts();
    comboBox1.DataSource = ports;
    //MessageBox.Show(ports.Count.ToString());
}

public IList<string> getSerialPorts()
        {
            List<string> serialPortResult = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                string wmiresult;

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%mbed% %Serial% %Port% %(COM%'");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    wmiresult = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

                    // Here we call Regex.Match.
                    Match match = Regex.Match(wmiresult, @"\bCOM\d+\b");

                    // Here we check the Match instance.
                    if (match.Success)
                    {

                        //combo.Add(queryObj["Caption"].ToString(), match.Value);
                        //comboBox1.Items.Add();
                        MessageBox.Show(match.Value);

                        serialPortResult.Add(match.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + er.Message);
            }

            return serialPortResult;
        }
```

Comment: Are you asking about `//combo.Add(queryObj["Caption"].ToString()` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are passing `Form` which is base class for forms in `System.Windows.Forms`. It will not give you access to combo you placed on your Form. You have to pass parameter of type of your Form (i.e. MyCustomForm).

Then your form needs to give access to this combo. For example you could add property that will return it. That would be the simplest, not the best.

But it would be a lot better if instead of passing form to your `setup` class you would call it and it return values that you then put in combo. This code would be placed in `computerButton_Click` method.

```
private void computerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var serialPorts = bsetup.getSerialPorts();
    // code to put serialPorts in combo
}
```

Your `setup` class should not know about visual controls.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I edited my original post with my code that works.